# Best practice for handling jquery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've done a lot of reading over the last few years trying to become proficient with JavaScript and it's frameworks.  It seems that most texts either teach the rudiments of ajax, loading something into an empty element, or they assume you know what your doing and glance over the data handling portion. I've developed my own methods over time, but having nothing to compare them too. I don't know how efficient they are. When building a ajax based site I typically use jquery and history.js and my code is as follows.

```
function updateContent(state){
    var theUrl = state.data.urlPath;  //the url of what needs ajaed in
    $('#container #content').fadeOut(500, function(){ //fade out old content
       var newContent = {};
       newContent.load(theUrl + ' #content', function(){ //load new content into object
           newContent.hide();  //hide it so it can be faded in
           $('#container').html(newContent);  //replace content in container
           newContent.fadeIn(500);  //fadein content
       });
    });
}

var History = window.History;
if (History.enabled) {
    var State = History.getState();
    History.pushState({urlPath: window.location.href}, $("title").text(), State.urlPath);
} else {
    return false;
}

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {  
    updateContent(History.getState());
});

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(evt){
    var testSite = /http:\/\/www.example.com(\/)?/ //regex to test if is local link
    var theUrl = $(this).attr('href'); //the url of the clicked link
    if(testSite.test(theUrl)){
        evt.preventDefault();
        History.pushState({urlPath: theUrl}, title, theUrl);
    }
});
```

This is the basics of my code.  I feel it is inefficient particularly when the back button is used. When going back the content has to be reloaded.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could use $.get instead and cache the responses in an object, then only send another $.get if it's for new data, otherwise what you're doing is fine as far as efficiency.

Comment: Your code looks fine in terms of efficiency, but one thing I need to add here is if you are moving to create a heavy ajax website, please make sure you are aborting the invalid or unused ajax calls. Like if you are checking any update on website and you are hitting ajax call periodically then make sure that while hitting the next ajax call, you abort the previous one or wait for that to complete.

Comment: @KevinB is it possible to store that html text in the history data object?

Comment: If it doesn't go over the limits of that datastore ( i don't know what  the limits are )